# Convert VBA codes to VB .net

Tags: vb.net

I need to convert these VBA codes to VB.Net in VS 2010. I have changed some of them, but Visual Studio pops up error messages. Can you please show me as a newbie doing this? Thanks

```
Public Function enc(strWord) As String
    Dim l , x As Integer
    Dim charA As String
    strPW = "aaaaaaardewbacimnkiolujpgvdrytfd"
     l = Len(strPW) 
      For x = 1 To Len(strWord)
         charA = Asc(Mid$(strPW, (x Mod l) - l * ((x Mod l) = 0), 1))
         Mid$(strWord, x, 1) = Chr$(Asc(Mid$(strWord, x, 1)) Xor charA)
      Next
    enc = strWord
End Function
```

My codes,

```
Public Function enc(ByVal strWord) As String
        Dim l, x As Integer
        Dim charA As String
        Dim strPW As String
        strPW = "aaaaaaardewbacimnkiolujpgvdrytfd"
        l = strPW.Length()
        For x = 1 To strWord.Length()
            charA = Convert.ToInt32(Mid(strPW, (x Mod l) - l * ((x Mod l) = 0), 1))
            Mid(strWord, x, 1) = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Mid(strWord, x, 1)) Xor charA)
        Next
        enc = strWord
    End Function
```

Comment: surely the error messages are not random!  perhaps you could help us help you by telling us what they are and where they are

Comment: You code compiles.  Whats the error?

Comment: System.FormatException was unhandled
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
       at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
       at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
       at Throwaway.Form1.enc(Object strWord) in c:\users\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Throwaway\Throwaway\Form1.vb:line 14

Comment: Dim a = Convert.ToInt32("a") is effectively what is failing

Answer (score 0):

Using  Convert.ToInt32 you are attempting to convert a string ("a") to an integer.  You want to use Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc instead.